# sqoop data from SQL Server, we are getting an error

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am getting error when listing table please help me out.

```
sqoop list-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://serverName=YYYYYYYY;database=Operational_Standards;integratedSecurity=true;authent
```

icationScheme=JavaKerberos"

> Warning: /usr/hdp/2.2.4.12-1/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
>
> Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
>
> INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5.2.2.4.12-1
>   INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
>
> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.12-1/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.12-1/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.12-1/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.4.12-1-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.c 
>   lass]
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>
> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>
> ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list tables 
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host serverName=YYYYY, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Comment: Can you connect to your SQL server from the Sqoop host using another client?

Comment: @HellmarBecker Yeah i connected sql through another client still it throws same error.

Comment: That could be a network problem. Can you ping the SQL Server host at all?

Comment: @HellmarBecker I pinged all SQL server Its fine Do you have another suggestions please